# How can I run angular 4 -not 2- application using the IIS

Tags: angular, typescript, iis

I have tried to run a simple “Hello world” application in angular 4 under the IIS; but all my trials failed (just displays a blank page without any errors!), i could only run it by one of the following ways:
1- if I built the application using the “ng build” CLI command, and then set the path of the website to the output directory.
2- if I run the application using the “ng serve” comman which run it using angular server not the IIS .
Briefly I need to write angular 4 application using visual studio and just press ctrl + f5 to run the application.
Note: it works fine using angular 2 but 4 I couldn’t.

Comment: Please put more effort with examples and error messages so people can help you out.

Comment: `angular 2` never had the capability of running in visual studio via CTRL F5 through `angular-cli`. What you're thinking is most likely using `SystemJS` not `webpack` created by `angular-cli`.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 (not Visual Studio Code) have a "Angular" template in Core 2.0 to work in Visual Studio and not with angular-cli

Comment: in https://dustinewers.com/angular-cli-with-net-core/ Dustin show as an angular-cli app runs in Visual Studio 2017 (but you must write ng build anytime)

Comment: Using <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script> in the index.html of an angular app (if you use Hastag strategies alow see the app in FireFox and Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

After Angular 2, these are the only main ways to run angular.
So, if you want to run under IIS, run it via the dist<projectname> folder - files appear in this folder after running ng build